# disabling kinect accelerometer

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ROS folks,

I wonder if there is any way to shut down kinect accelemotor. I need to mount the kinect in angular way and still have the full tilting range. Accelemotor prevents kinect to go towards up even though it is looking down! I looked at kinect_aux, there are all of the controls except this.

Any advice?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32533/disabling-kinect-accelerometer/) by [Amin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2235/amin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2012-04-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Again,

After some tests, I realized that even using the trick above you are not able to get more than -60 degrees on tilting kinect. In other words, kinect is able to tilt down -30 degrees itself (according to kinecy_aux stack) and at the same time you are also able to mount the kinect stand with about -30 degrees (more than this figure would not have effect since accelerometer does not allow kinect to go down further even though it can go!) so both of them would give 60 degrees.

My goal was to mount the kinect on the ceiling of my room in such a way that the FOV of kinect would be vertical against the ground. By doing that 60 degrees (30 tilting + 30 mounting angle) with a FOV of (43/2 ~ 22) I could get to -82 and not -90!

Any advice on how to come up with accelerometer is appreciated.

---

Originally posted by [Amin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2235/amin/) with karma: 93 on 2012-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just found the answer.

in kinect_aux.cpp, simply comment out

angle = (angle<MIN_TILT_ANGLE) ? MIN_TILT_ANGLE : ((angle>MAX_TILT_ANGLE) ? MAX_TILT_ANGLE : angle);

Recompile, and tilt more that 31 or less than -31. I guess you should be very careful to not to over tilt the kinect.

---

Originally posted by [Amin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2235/amin/) with karma: 93 on 2012-04-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bublator](https://answers.ros.org/users/6367/bublator/) on 2013-09-03**:
Where can I find this file?